# Why can't I use let! (let bang) inside a try/with expression?

Tags: f#

I'm making a call to an async function from inside a `task {...}` computation expression. I can normally use `let!` to call async functions and await their results. However, if I move the function call into a `try/with` expression, I get the following compiler error.

`This construct may only be used within computation expressions`

Since this code is still within the `task{...}` expression, I'm not sure what the compiler means exactly.

In the following contrived example the call to `getDataMayThrowAsync` from `controller1` compiles, but in `controller2` I get the above compile error.

```ml
module LetBangIssue =

    open System
    open System.Threading.Tasks

    let getDataMayThrowAsync (id:int) = task {
        do! Task.Delay(10)
        let random = Random()
        if random.Next(1, 1000) < 500 then
            raise <| Exception "Something went wrong"
            
        return "the data"
    }

    // Compiles, but doesn't handle error case...
    let controller1() = task {
        let! tryGetTheData = getDataMayThrowAsync 10
        return tryGetTheData
    }

    // Attempt to handle error case, but can't compile...
    let controller2 () = task {
        let theData =
            try
                let! tryGetTheData = getDataMayThrowAsync 10
                tryGetTheData
            with
            | ex ->
                printfn $"Error: {ex.Message}"
                "couldn't get the data"
                
        return theData
    }
```

How can I fix `controller2` to solve the compile error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `try`/`with` that's the problem. It's the extra `let`. Try this:

```
let controller2 () = task {
    let theData =
            let! tryGetTheData = getDataMayThrowAsync 10
            tryGetTheData
            
    return theData
}
```

This fails with the same error, because in the body of `theData` you're using `let!` without a surrounding `task { }`.

As written, the extra `let` is not needed at all, since you're just returning it at the end. So this would work fine:

```
let controller2 () = task {
    try
        let! tryGetTheData = getDataMayThrowAsync 10
        return tryGetTheData
    with
    | ex ->
        printfn $"Error: {ex.Message}"
        return "couldn't get the data"
}
```

But if you really need the extra `let`, you have to make it a `let!` (because it's bound to an async result), you have to wrap its body in `task` (otherwise you can't use `let!` inside it), and you have to use `return` to return the values from it:

```
let controller2 () = task {
    let! theData = task {
        try
            let! tryGetTheData = getDataMayThrowAsync 10
            return tryGetTheData
        with
        | ex ->
            printfn $"Error: {ex.Message}"
            return "couldn't get the data"
    }
            
    return theData
}
```

Comment: This is great! May I ask a follow up question? One of my attempts to correct the compile error was `let tryGetTheData = getDataMayThrowAsync 10 |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously`. That seemed to work but didn't feel like the right approach. I'm not sure why. Are the Async functions inappropriate in a case like this?

Comment: Your attempt made the whole thing synchronous. Rather than catching computation results via continuations (aka "callbacks"), your solution would stop the thread and wait for the async task to complete, then continue.

Comment: Ah yes. I see that now. It looks like `Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously` is similar to `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in C#.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Except I think it's a bit more explicit about what's going on due to having "Synchronously" in the name.